# Set text format on Qlabel on a number

Tags: qt, qlabel, text-formatting

I am writing my first application on Qt. So far, to display any text on a `QLabel` I was using the following to set the format and the text:

```
ui->lat_UAV_label->setText(QString("<span style=\" font-size:18pt; 
  font-weight:600; color:#0009d8;\">%1</span>").arg(lat * RAD2DEG));
```

where "lat" is a double precision number and "RAD2DEG" is a constant to convert from radians to degrees. However, I only want to display 2 decimal digits on the label. I tried to do it using `QString().number`, but then the format styling is lost:

```
ui->lat_UAV_label->setText(QString("<span style=\" font-size:18pt; 
    font-weight:600; color:#0009d8;\">%1</span>").number(lat * RAD2DEG, 'f', 2);
```

I have tried other ways to do it, but it doesn't work. I think this should be much simpler than what I'm trying to do, but because I'm new to it, I don't know it.

Comment: The [`arg` method itself](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg-8) has arguments to set the formatting of doubles

Comment: I would use setFont for QLabel also instead of setting font with style because now your code is quite unreadable

Answer (score 0):

I had tried that @Karsten Koop, but I had done it wrong so I thought I couldn't do it that way. Thanks a lot, it's working now:

```
ui->lat_UAV_label->setText(QString(myBlueStyle).arg(lat * RAD2DEG, 0, 'f', 2);
```

where `myBlueStyle` is defined as:

```
QString myBlueStyle = "<span style=\" font-size:18pt; font-weight:600; color:#0009d8;\">%1</span>";
```